# Displaying spring form error outside of form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How can we display form errors out side of form. I know it can be displayed inside of form using `<sf:errors path="nb"></sf:errors>`. If I want to display it in separate `div` how can I do it? I am new to spring so please guide me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could, if you're planning to display all error messages simultaneously, using the following taglib.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
```

Something like,

```
<spring:hasBindErrors htmlEscape="true" name="someBean">
    <c:if test="${errors.errorCount gt 0}">
    <h4>The error list :</h4>
    <font color="red">
      <c:forEach items="${errors.allErrors}" var="error">
        <spring:message code="${error.code}"
                        arguments="${error.arguments}"
                        text="${error.defaultMessage}"/><br/>
      </c:forEach>
    </font>
  </c:if>   
</spring:hasBindErrors>
```

Note that the name attribute `name="someBean"` of the tag [`<spring:hasBindErrors/>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/taglib/tag/BindErrorsTag.html) is your actual command object which is bound to your form.