# How to check conditionally an empty validation error message from Spring in JSP?

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl, el

I have a simple question. We can display error messages generated by validators of Spring something like the following.

```
<form:errors path='edId' cssStyle='font-weight: normal; color: red;'/>
```

I'm displaying such messages using some HTML like `<ul><li></li></ul>` and CSS. Therefore, even though there is no error, a blank bullet is displayed unnecessarily.

I therefore need to check conditionally on the JSP page whether the message is actually blank or not, something like,

```
<c:if test="${not empty edIdError}">
    <form:errors path='edId' cssStyle='font-weight: normal; color: red;'/>       
</c:if>
```

But testing this `if` condition requires storing the error message into some variable on JSP like `<c:set var="edIdError"/>` (as an example) which doesn't seem possible to me. Is it possible? Is there any other way to do this?

Anyway, I want to show the message with some HTML and CSS only when it is not empty. I'm using Spring 3.2.0.

And yes, I have a different scenario and cannot use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14872463/1391249) approach.

Comment: This makes your messaging a little ugly, but can't you just bury your tags into your spring messages?  So instead of something like "Sorry you forgot to enter X", your message.properties would print out "<li>Sorry you forgot to enter X</li>".

Comment: @Joe - I thought the same ugly way before asking this question. I ultimately met with the way that is quite obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have forgotten a simple thing about the `<c:set>` JSTL tag. It's a container tag. Therefore, it is obviously possible to enclose the `<form:errors>` tag within it like the following.

```
<c:set var="edIdError"><form:errors path='edId'/></c:set>
```

It sets the variable `edIdError` to the actual error message from Spring. So, it is now possible to check this conditionally whether it is null (and empty) or not like,

```
<c:if test="${not empty edIdError}">
    <form:errors path='edId' cssStyle='font-weight: normal; color: red;'/>
</c:if>
```

There is no need to use the `value` attribute of the `<c:set>` tag in this scenario. I could use HTML and apply CSS within the `<c:if>` conditional block as I needed.